# Estout: indicate() continuous/factorial interaction terms

Tags: label, latex, regression, stata

I'm trying to indicate whether a regression includes an interaction term between a factorial and a continuous variable as below:

```
sysuse auto
eststo: reg price mpg c.weight#i.rep78
esttab, indicate(Interaction = *rep78#c.weight)
```

I get an error saying

> coefficient *rep78#c.weight not found

I've tried many alternative ways of calling the coefficient but have run out of ideas. Any suggestions on how to call it?

Comment: Your example works for me with Stata 14.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of estout? Roughly June 2015.

Comment: if my question helps please accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to define them manually

```
1.rep78#c.weight
2.rep78#c.weight
etc
```